# auto Copy Filemaker data to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, filemaker

I'm new to File maker but not to databases.  I'm having trouble navigating my way around a prefab-ed File maker solution that we use for a specific business process.  I would like to get 2 fields out of a table and copy them to a MySQL table so that I can manipulate the data in a database that I am more familiar with.  Ideally I would like this to happen automatically when data is updated or daily at a specified time.

Basically I want to do what this SQL statement would to, then copy the results to another table (a MySQL table) and not alter the original data at all.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM fmTable WHERE field3 = 1
```

I'd prefer to do this from MySQL through a connector so that I leave the original FM solution untouched, but if it is only possible to do the select and push from FM I can do it that way too.

I have access to File maker Pro, Pro Advanced, and FM Server; if any of that makes a difference or helps.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saying which FileMaker version you are using, but in general, if you set up your FileMaker Pro or Server as an ODBC source, you can access the data directly with SQL.

[This](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13293/~/configuring-a-dsn-for-filemaker-odbc-drivers) article from FileMaker support describes how to set up the DSN and ODBC client driver.

Comment: Sorry, I always forget something.  FM 14 for now, upgrading to 16 soon.  I'll give this a try.  Looks like it will work perfectly.  Thanks!